# По нажатию на кнопку добавить класс на разный блок

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.
Пока меня не закидали тапками, что я не умею добавить по нажатию на кнопку на блок класс, спешу заметить, что такое я умею. У меня на данный момент другая ситуация.
Есть блок с неограниченным количеством дочерних элементов, количество я получаю по нажатию на кнопку, вот так:

```
    $('.range__read-more--link').click(function () {
    var slide = $('.range__slider__item--wrapper').children();
    for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
        console.log(slide[i]);
    }
});
```

Нужно по одному нажатию на кнопку добавлять на один из дочерних элементов каждый раз класс. Вот с этим у меня возникло затруднение, и я прошу у вас помощи.
Если я указываю

```
$(slide[i]).addClass('active');
```

То у меня добавляется этот класс на все дочерние блоки.

```
<section class="range">
<div class="slider range__slider">
    <div class="range__slider__item--wrapper">
        <div class="range__slider__item">
            <div class="range__slider__img"><img src="img/production-items-1.png"></div>
            <div class="range__slider__info mCustomScrollbar">
                <div class="range__slider__info__title">Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также укрепление.
                </div>
                <p class="range__slider__info__description">Номенклатура конвейерных лент Nitta по-настоящему широкая</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="range__slider__item--wrapper">
        <div class="range__slider__item">
            <div class="range__slider__img"><img src="img/production-items-1.png"></div>
            <div class="range__slider__info mCustomScrollbar">
                <div class="range__slider__info__title">Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также укрепление
                </div>
                <p class="range__slider__info__description">Номенклатура конвейерных лент Nitta по-настоящему широкая</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="range__read-more--link">Читать дальше</div>
```

Добавить класс нужно на range__slider__item--wrapper

А как сделать, что бы когда мы добавим на все дочерние блоки класс, кнопка скрывалась?
Я добавила

```
if (curSlide > slides.length) {
        $('.range__read-more--link').hide();
    }
```

Но, скрывается, когда нажимаешь на кнопку, а мне нужно, когда показывается последний дочерний элемент, тогда и скрываем кнопку.

Вопрос решен, забыла добавить >= вместо >

Comment: Вы хотите элементу с конкретным индексом добавлять класс?

Comment: И как определять, на какой именно надо класс вешать?

Comment: У меня есть родитель .range__slider, в нем есть блоки .range__slider__item--wrapper, вот на них мне и нужно навесить класс.

Comment: @МашаПузырь понятнее не стало. Во-первых, добавьте в вопрос минимальный пример HTML Во-вторых, всё-таки определитесь на кого из детей (`children`) нужно навесить класс. Если на всех, то в чём проблема? Или вообще `children()` берутся не те, что вам нужны?

Comment: @МашаПузырь как выбрать конкретный элемент для добавления класса: на все последовательно или в случайном порядке или как?

Comment: @br3t, на все имеющиеся последовательно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навешиваем класс последовательно тем элементам, у которых его еще нет:

```js
var curSlide = 0;
var slides = $('.range__slider').find('.range__slider__item--wrapper');

function highLightSlide() {
  slides.removeClass('active');
  slides.eq(curSlide % slides.size()).addClass('active');
  curSlide++;
}

$('.range__read-more--link').click(function() {
  highLightSlide();
});
highLightSlide();
```

```css
.active {
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="range__read-more--link">Click</button>
<div class="range__slider">
  <div class="range__slider__item--wrapper">1</div>
  <div class="range__slider__item--wrapper">2</div>
  <div class="range__slider__item--wrapper">3</div>
  <div class="range__slider__item--wrapper">4</div>
  <div class="range__slider__item--wrapper">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это вы где вычитали, что на блоки нужно по очереди класс навешивать?

Comment: @Regent  "По очереди" я предположил, возможен вариант "добавить рендомному блоку", но скорее похоже на последовательное чтение статей в каком-нибудь слайдере.

Comment: @br3t, да, вы правы, это слайдер, но на мобильном мне нужно его скрыть, и по нажатию на кнопку показывать "следующий слайд"

Comment: @МашаПузырь , поправил на "все последовательно"

Comment: @br3t, спасибо вам огромное)))) Все работает, я только slides.size() заменила на slides.length, ато ругалось почему то.

Answer (score 2):

Ограничьте выборку тем блоком, на котором щелкнули мышью:

```
var slide = $(this).closest('.range__slider').
  find('.range__slider__item--wrapper').children();
```